# errorInfo not worked properly

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

I'm trying to write a comprehensive API with php to take action.
So that even if one of the input queries is not executed, it should be canceled and other views should not be executed.
And this is done well.
But the problem is that the command `errorInfo ()` has an error only if you run 1 Query, for example:

```
INSERT INTO Funds (City, BuyDate, PhoneNo) Values ('london', '2019/01/01', 0554);
```

But if you have multiple Query, the command `errorInfo ()` will show the value of `[0000,null,null]` . for example:

```
INSERT INTO Funds (City ,BuyDate, PhoneNo ) VALUES ('london', '2019/01/01',0554);

INSERT INTO HouseholdAdmin (HouseholdAdminId ,AdminCode , FundId ) VALUES (2,2,1);
```

The second queue, `HouseholdAdmin`, contains an error, but  the`errorInfo ()` command ,work,only if it is run alone.

My Api:

```php
include "connect.php";

$inputdata = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$query = "SELECT * FROM QueryBank WHERE QueryName=:name";
$result = $connect->prepare($query);
$result->bindParam("name", $inputdata["ViewName"]);

$result->execute();

if ($row = $result->FETCH(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $query2 = $row["QueryString"];
    $parameters = $inputdata["parameters"];

    for ($x = 0; $x < count($parameters); $x++) {
        $query2 = str_replace($inputdata["parameters"][$x]["key"], $inputdata["parameters"][$x]["value"], $query2);
    }

    $back = array();
    $back["code"] = 0000;
    $back["error"] = null;

    try {
        $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $connect->beginTransaction();
        $result2 = $connect->prepare($query2);
        $result2->execute();
        $connect->commit();
        echo json_encode($back);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $connect->rollback();

        $back["code"] = $result2->errorInfo()[1];
        $back["error"] = $result2->errorInfo()[2];
        echo json_encode($back);
    }
}
```

It should be noted that the queries are stored in a table and called and executed with a select statement.

Comment: you are doing something extremely strange here. It makes no sense to use try and catch operator if exceptions are disabled. Please provide the **Full [MCVE](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mcve)** for your problem as it's extremely unclear for now.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should enable the Exception mode for all queries:

```php
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
];

$connect= new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
```

Then wrap all queries into a try/catch block and then use the Exception object to get the last error.

```php
} catch (Exception $e) {
   $connect->rollback();

   $back["code"] = $e->getCode();
   $back["error"] = $e->getMessage();
   echo json_encode($back);
}
```

Comment: I am using an exception, but it does not go into an exception because one of the two queries  contain error.

Comment: Then try to enable the Exception mode for all queries (see my example).

Comment: Did not work (it does not work for Multi queries). I found it and placed it in the post. Anyway thanks for your the help.